# How to convert a comma separated string to comma separated integers and pass it as parameters in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have been trying to convert comma separated string "5430,5456,5450", the length of the string is varying, to comma separated integers and use it in a stored proc as  a parameter to query the db whose column route_id is of number type.

I have seen some examples but nothing seems to be working. These are the parameters and the query:

```
P_business_date IN VARCHAR2,
  P_route_ids IN VARCHAR2

SELECT  rt.route_id , rt.route_name, i.data_file_name, i.bus_date,                 stdesc.status_code,  i.batch_in_id In_Id , i.modified_date In_Time

                FROM gthdba.gth_in_batch i , gthdba.gth_route rt , gthdba.gth_route_source_status st , gthdba.gth_status stdesc 
                WHERE rt.route_id =  i.route_id 
                AND rt.route_id = st.route_id 
                AND st.run_seq_no = i.run_seq_no 
                AND stdesc.status_id = st.status_Id
                AND i.bus_date = to_date (''' || P_business_date || ''','' YYYYMMDD'')
                AND RT.ROUTE_ID IN  (''' || P_route_ids || ''')
                AND i.modified_date > to_date (''' || P_business_date ||  '',''YYYYMMDD '')
                ORDER BY IN_ID DESC, ROUTE_ID';
```

Thanks

Comment: SQL or PL/SQL solution is needed?

Comment: Hi @VladimirChervanev PL/SQL solution is needed,thanks.

Comment: You can [split](https://blogs.oracle.com/aramamoo/entry/how_to_split_comma_separated_string_and_pass_to_in_clause_of_select_statement) an input string using plain SQL. Do you need additional details? Or use INSTR, as it shown below.

Answer (score 2):

The initial solution can't work since `string1 in (string2)` returns true if string1 == string2. (btw, it could be modified to work as a "dynamic SQL", try it if you wish).

Quick but not the fastest solution is:

```
SELECT ...
        FROM ...
            AND i.bus_date = to_date (P_business_date,'YYYYMMDD')
            AND INSTR(''' || P_route_ids || ''', ''' || RT.ROUTE_ID || ''') != 0
            AND i.modified_date > to_date (P_business_date,'YYYYMMDD')
            ORDER BY IN_ID DESC, ROUTE_ID';
```

[INSTR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_1103.htm) function returns substring position in the input string.

For instance, a route has id `10` and the parameter is `10,20,30`:

```
instr(',10,20,30,', ',10,') != 0
```

and the route will be selected.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative approach is to change the procedure to parse the `p_route_ids` string and insert the unique integer values into a temporary table. This means that you can then change your query to join to the temporary table rather than using `AND rt.route_id IN (...)`.

Comment: That's too complicated. I think a (v)array does the same.

Answer (score 0):

Hey all thanks for the post,

I thik i have found another solution to my question,it involves the use of xmltables, a function . It sores the input string in my case || p_route_id || to a temporary table as a column and u can select the coulmn that is column_values and cast it to the integer type and use it so my query will now look like this

AND RT.ROUTE_ID IN (SELECT TO_NUMBER (column_value) FROM  XMLTABLE ('''|| P_route_ids || '''))

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by using CTE statements. Here is the sample of my way . It is searching m.your_columnX in the str and m.your_columnY   in the str2.

```
with rws as
     (select '1080,5020' str from dual),
    rws2 as
     (select 'abc,def' str2 from dual)
    select m.your_column1,m.your_column2
      from your_table m
     where m.your_columnX in
           (select nvl(regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, level),m.your_columnX) value
              from rws
            connect by level <= length(str) - length(replace(str, ',')) + 1)
       and m.your_columnY in
           (select nvl(regexp_substr(str2, '[^,]+', 1, level),m.your_columnY) value
              from rws2
            connect by level <= length(str2) - length(replace(str2, ',')) + 1)
```